# Change wordpress homepage based on login status

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm making a website with users and working with the buddyboss theme & platform. I want to change the homepage based on user login status. If a user is logged in, set one page as the homepage. If not, select the second page as the homepage.

I have tried too many things, and I have also made it work, but the problem is that sometimes logged-in users see logged-out users' homepage and it starts working again after a refresh. Somehow, it has too many problems anyway and doesn't work as expected.

I think it's because of the if/else statement.

I have added this snippet directly at functions.php

```
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
  $about = get_page_by_title( 'Front Page Logged In' );
  update_option( 'page_on_front', $about->ID );
  update_option( 'show_on_front', 'page' );
} else {
  $about = get_page_by_title( 'Front Page Logged Out' );
  update_option( 'page_on_front', $about->ID );
  update_option( 'show_on_front', 'page' );
}
```

It doesn't work and does what I said at the top, it shows you logged out the page for logged-in users sometimes, and it's a problem.

Then I wrap this up like that, and it's even worse.

```
add_action( 'init', 'switch_homepage' );
function switch_homepage() {
    if( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        $page = get_page_by_title( 'Front Page Logged In');
        update_option( 'page_on_front', $page->ID );
        update_option( 'show_on_front', 'page' );
    } else {
        $page = get_page_by_title( 'Front Page Logged Out' );
        update_option( 'page_on_front', $page->ID );
        update_option( 'show_on_front', 'page' );
    }
}
```

Now, I'm looking for ways to show one page for logged-in users and the second page as the homepage for logged-out/guest users. Any insights into how to make this work would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can use the init hook and use wp_redirect() function to send your user wherever you want based on the result of wp_get_current_user() result.

Something like that.

```
add_action('init', function () {
    if ($user = wp_get_current_user()) {
        if (in_array('my-custom-role', $user->roles)) {
            wp_redirect('/my-custom-url');
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: It’s not what i’m looking for. it will just redirect and page slug will change. i want to change homepage, not link